# Changing iPhone 11 torch/flashlight brightness with Swift does not seem to work properly

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, brightness, flashlight

I'm trying to make an iOS app where I can turn the torch on and change the brightness.

I'm testing it on iPhone 11 with iOS 13.3.1 and Xcode 11.3.1

I used one of the solutions here: [How to turn flashlight ON and OFF in swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27207278/how-to-turn-flashlight-on-and-off-in-swift)

Everything works perfectly if I use:

`try self.device.setTorchModeOn(level: AVCaptureDevice.maxAvailableTorchLevel)`

I can turn it on and off freely.

but if I try to change the brightness like this (using `var someFloat: Float` from 0.1 to 1):

`try self.device.setTorchModeOn(level: someFloat)`

everything goes haywire. The brightness dims, but then dims too much. Then, even if I use `AVCaptureDevice.maxAvailableTorchLevel`, it stays extremely dim. And the only way to restore it is to restart my iPhone. Then it's bright again until I try to mess with the level.

Anyone seen this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [iOS: Torch level on iPhone 11 Pro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60197045/ios-torch-level-on-iphone-11-pro)